# Установка позиции метки в центр формы через Label.Location

Tags: c#

Pos2 при расчёте, в выводе на консоль - верном, всё же устанавливает существенно ниже середины точку.

```
using System; 
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Windows.Forms;

class ClassExample
{ 
    public static void Main() 
    {       
        Form Form1 = new Form(); 
        Form1.Text = "Example"; 
        Form1.Width *= 2;       
        Form1.Size = new Size( 1366 , 768 );

        Label Label1 = new Label();     
        Label1.Visible = true;
        Label1.Text = "123456789";
        Label1.AutoSize = true;
        Point Point1 = new Point( 1366 / 2 - Label1.Size.Width / 2, 768 +
                                               Label1.Size.Height / 2);      
        Label1.Location = new Point(Point1.X, Point1.Y); //не воспринимает
        Label1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        Label1.Font = new Font("Verdana", 21 );

        Form1.Controls.Add(Label1);

        Console.WriteLine(Point1.X + " " + Point1.Y);

        Application.Run(Form1);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте по порядку:

1. Вместо `Width` и `Height` формы лучше использовать `ClientRectangle.Width` и `ClientRectangle.Height`, т.к. в первом случае будет учитываться еще и шапка формы, отсюда и небольшой "съезд" получается.
2. Задание шрифта нужно делать **ДО** высчитывания координат, потому что если поле `AutoSize` установлено в `true`, то после изменения шрифта размеры `Label'a` изменятся
3. При высчитывании координаты `Y Label'a`, вы должны поделить `768` на 2 и **отнять** `Label1.Height` деленное на два, а не прибавить, т.к. точка `(0;0)` находится в левом верхнем углу формы
4. И на последок - не пишите при расчете конкретные цифры высоты и длины формы, представьте что вы решили поменять размеры формы? Вам придется везде менять "ручками" эти значения по коду. А если бы Вы сделали так:

   Point Point1 = new Point(Form1.Width / 2 - Label1.Width / 2, Form1.Height / 2 - Label1.Height / 2);

   То поменяв размеры формы в строчке `Form1.Size = new Size(1366, 768);`

   Вы везде уже будете обращаться к новым значениям

Comment: Спасибо большое.
з.ы. по поводу 3-го я сюда(на хешкод) старый с ошибкой код запостил, виноват.